# Firebase Analytics Content graph showing duplicate data

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-analytics

I have setup Firebase analytics in Xamarin project.It works perfectly and I'm able to capture all content type that I customize. But there is something off with the Content Chart showed below. On IOS app, the first top 2 content type is the same. Same parameter and same value. What could be the cause?

I have looked into:

- Logevent is only written once in PCL project.
- I made sure there is no typo or the same parameter in the code
- It happen only for IOS app, android is fine.
- No matter what parameter name first top 2 is always the same.

Does anyone of you encountered this before?

Thank you for your response.

[image]